# Requirements for implementing _rvs in subclass of scipy.stats.rv_continuous?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I'd like to implement a particular distribution in terms of the `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` class, and I'd like to provide my own implementation of `_rvs`  but I don't understand what
arguments come into it (it's just `*args` in the function declaration).

In particular, I don't see how the `size` parameter feeds into the call to `_rvs` via 
the `rv_generic.rvs` function call (line  665 in [online source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/distributions.py#L849)).

My distribution does not have any parameters (other than `loc` and `scale`),
so if `_rvs` just needs to return 1 random value, I could do that with an empty argument list, but it seems like it needs to return a (flat) array of random values,
how do I obtain the number of elements to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` class is a subclass of `rv_generic`. The latter defines a `rv_generic.rvs` function that calls `self._rvs` after having set its `self._size` variable to either `None`, or a specific number. This is done by reading the keyword arguments stored in `**kwds` and checking for a `size` parameter.

Usually, when `self._size` is `None`, distributions return a scalar and otherwise return an array of length `self._size`.

Comment: to be more precise: of shape ``self._size`` for more than 1 dimensional arrays.

Comment: @user333700 I'm not sure. The `size` keyword parameter specifies the shape, but `self._size` should specify the number of variates. The `rv_generic.rvs` function will reshape it.